# File_get_contents выдаёт старое значение

Tags: php

Собственно, file_get_contents выдаёт старое значение. Если страница минуту назад была <lol>3</lol>. А теперь она <lol>11</lol>. То при запросе выдаёт <lol>3</lol>

Comment: @Vlmake, скорее всего контент кэшируется на каком-то уровне. Ответ прост - хранить данные в БД.

Comment: Данные не с моего сервера. Как убрать кеширование??

Comment: @Vlmake, интересно, а как нужно было догадаться, что вы запрашиваете что-то по http? Добавьте GET-параметр nonce равный текущему timestamp в url, должно помочь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ошибка у вас в скрипте где-то. Про кеширование ничего не скажу, но вроде file_get_contents  не кэширует (покрайней мере я не встречал в документации такую особенность)